# How to avoid duplicate columns in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I'm very new to ms sql and joins. Please can someone guide me through this process.

The query below works, however it duplicates a lot of columns that are in both tables.

```
Select *
From ['BP Ref _ Customer Name$']
inner join ['Road 2010 - Current$']
on ['BP Ref _ Customer Name$'].[Client Order]=['Road 2010 - Current$'].[Client Order]
```

However, when I try to specify the columns I want the query to select in ['BP Ref _ Customer Name$'] table I get an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If each table has the same column names you will need to specify which one you want to bring through.

Using your query you could for example use
`SELECT ['BP Ref _ Customer Name$'].col_name FROM...`

Or better still give each table an alias eg

```
Select CUST.col_1, CURRENT.col_2
From ['BP Ref _ Customer Name$'] AS CUST
inner join ['Road 2010 - Current$'] AS CURRENT on CUST.[Client Order]=CURRENT.[Client Order]
```

Answer (score 1):

First, use table aliases.  Second, explicitly list the columns you want.  Third, rename the ones that are duplicates.

```
select c.col1 as c_col1, cn.col1 as cn_col1, . . .
from ['BP Ref _ Customer Name$'] cn join
     ['Road 2010 - Current$'] c
     on cn.[Client Order] = c.[Client Order]
```

You *can * select all columns from one table and then just rename the columns from the other:

```
select c.*, cn.col1 as cn_col1, . . .
from ['BP Ref _ Customer Name$'] cn join
     ['Road 2010 - Current$'] c
     on cn.[Client Order] = c.[Client Order]
```